# Object destructuring bound

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, object-destructuring

Ok, I **really love** Object destructuring feature. But I've found a use case that can't be achieved by destructuring as far as I know.

Supose a Helper class to format things (be forgiving with my example please).

```js
 function Helper() {
    return {
        _doSomethingElse: function(str) {
            // Something else gets done with str
            str = str + str.length;
            return str;
        },

        formatStr: function(str) {
            // Do something with str
            str = str.toUpperCase();

            // do something else with str
            str = this._doSomethingElse(str);

            return str;
        }
    }
}
```

Normally I can use this method by

```js
// Normal usage *****************************************
var HelperInst = new Helper();

var str="Test";
var formattedStr = HelperInst.formatStr(str); // Call method of helper class

console.log(formattedStr); // Outputs: TEST4
```

But, it happens that I need to format *a lot* of strings (stay with me on this please). I would normally do a destructuring.

```js
// Destructuring (error) *********************************
var { formatStr } = HelperInst; // I want to extract this method because I have to use ir many times
var str="Test";
var formattedStr = formatStr(str); // TypeError: this._doSomethingElse is not a function

console.log(formattedStr);
```

Oops! `TypeError`.

Logically the `formatStr` local variable is not bound to the Class instance so it is calling an unknown `this._doSomethingElse`.

I've found a workaround, but it implies to give up the so-loved destructured syntax.

```js
// Explicit binding **************************************
var formatStr = HelperInst.formatStr.bind(HelperInst);
var str="Test";
var formattedStr = formatStr(str);

console.log(formattedStr); // Outputs: TEST4
```

Is there a nicer workaround? One that can, par example, work for "bound destructuring" many properties?

---

## Explanatory update:

Seeing that many answers pointed out correctly a vague or even wrong architecture implementation. I need to clarify this:

The thing I wanted to know was if there were a way to get a **bound reference** of the object method (like the one made with `ref = X.Y.bind(X)` ) by means of object destructuring, as I consider this could be a nice and useful feature... It was not a question about Architecture and Design Patterns

Comment: this doesn't really related to destructuring. simple `let formatStr = HelperInst.formatStr` doesn't preserve `this` either.

Comment: for your use case I'd say it may be easier to make helper not depend on `this`

Comment: Ok, what I try to know is if there is another workaround, nicer or cleaner than using .bind() -which works perfectly-...

Comment: Let's consider that Helper class (or any class indeed) could be complex enough to need modularization of behaviors. Which is, in fact, a good thing, not something to avoid.

Comment: like I said, destructuring has nothing to do with `this` binding. And, module or not is not related to destructuring either

Comment: Since your object has no instance data, why don't you just use either plain functions or static functions on the class.  Then, you won't have this issue of referencing `this` that is not needed here.  You could use `.bind()` to fix the issue with `this`, but that's an artificial issue since `this` isn't really needed anyway (because there is no instance data) so you may as well just fix the design to not depend upon `this` at all.

Comment: Yes jfriend00 you are correct, in this simplified example would be a good choice. But this example is just an abstraction of a much more complicated, modularized app, where Helper class can be imported in many components and can hold complex logic and need to use """private""" methods.

Comment: Then could you give a [mre] that _is_ representative of what you're actually working with? Realistically `HelperInst.formatStr` better communicates that this is a method that relies on the instance context, which destructuring (if it did work) obscures, so you might be trying to solve the wrong problem. *"Is there a nicer workaround?"* - how would you determine whether something was nicer?

Comment: It is a minimal reporducible example @jonrsharpe, I've tested every single part of code before posting the question. The thing is that, the question is oriented to the method calling part, assuming that the class implementation is not in debate (because of pattern imposed by the framework). Sorry maybe I had to be more explicit in this last statement.

Comment: I'm not saying you didn't test it, I'm saying it doesn't represent what you're actually working with, because _as you said_ the solutions to this example don't solve the actual problem (and also that you probably just _shouldn't use destructuring_).

Comment: ""*Let's consider that Helper class (or any class indeed) could be complex enough to need modularization of behaviors.*" then use a module and import it. Done. Your `Helper` is not [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID). It's a collection of random behaviours that don't need to be instance bound. Your other option is a class with static methods which would *work* but also basically admits does not fit into OOP. Which is why a module is a really nice fit here as it would act exactly like you want - you can import it, you can have "private" functionality that's not exposed.

Comment: Undoubtedly right @VLAZ. The thing is, that I have an opinionated framework as SAP UI5 over me that wouldn't like it that way... I deeply agree with you in this comment and I realize now that my intention to generalize this as a JS topic, not a UI5 scoped, might have introduced unnecessary noise

Answer (score 1):

One option is to do the binding within your constructor. Something like this:

```
function Helper() {
    let instance = {
        _doSomethingElse: function(str) {
            // Something else gets done with str
            str = str + str.length;
            return str;
        }
    };
    
    instance.formatStr = (function (str) {
        // Do something with str
        str = str.toUpperCase();

        // do something else with str
        str = this._doSomethingElse(str);

        return str;
    }).bind(instance);
    
    return instance;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d49j6zur/

Another option that does not involve `bind` is to reference the internal `instance` variable in your functions rather than `this`. Like so:

```
function Helper() {
    let instance = {};
    
    instance.formatStr = function (str) {
        // Do something with str
        str = str.toUpperCase();

        // do something else with str
        str = _doSomethingElse(str);

        return str;
    };
    
    function _doSomethingElse(str) {
        // if necessary, refer to "instance" in here rather than "this"
        // Something else gets done with str
        str = str + str.length;
        return str;
    }
    
    return instance;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vf8tLnd2/

Note that you can also use an internal reference to `this` rather than a new object instance:

```
function Helper() {
    let instance = this;
```

This is how I typically see TypeScript transpiled.

Comment: Thank Jack, that is a good one. But it implies to adopt a Singleton pattern that is not intended to.

Comment: @cape_bsas Each call to the constructor will create a new instance of `instance`, so no, it will not be a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

*this answer focus on how to provide helper class* that don't rely on `this`, which from OP's comments I assume can also solve the problem*

---

You can use closure instead of `this` (and have better *private method*)

---

```js
let helper = new Helper();
let {formatStr} = helper;
console.log(formatStr("Hello"))

function Helper() {
  function _doSomethingElse(str) {
    str = str + str.length;
    return str;
  }

  function formatStr(str) {
    str = str.toUpperCase();
    str = _doSomethingElse(str);
    return str;
  }
  return {formatStr}
}
```

---

*in this specific case I'd prefer free function

Comment: Nice one @apple apple! I was looking for an answer more focused on the "consuming" part instead of the Class design. But definitely this would work as choice

Answer (score 1):

Create a Helper [module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules):

```
function doSomethingElse(str) {
    // Something else gets done with str
    str = str + str.length;
    return str;
}

export function formatStr(str) {
    // Do something with str
    str = str.toUpperCase();

    // do something else with str
    str = doSomethingElse(str);

    return str;
}
```

Then import it in other files and use it as you wish:

```
import { formatStr } from './Helper'

const result = formatStr(prompt("Enter something"));
document.getElementById("formatted_output").textContent = result;
```

```
import { formatStr } from './Helper'

db.readSomeDate()
    .then(str => formatStr(str))
    .then(formatted => db.writeSomeData(formatted));
```

Your `Helper` instance does not rely at all on instance data. There is really no reason for it to exist except to collect your functions together. That is *exactly* the role of a module.

Modules offer easy reuse of functions that *may* rely on each other or not. You can choose which gets exposed and how you even get the functions. Modules can be nested in order to keep your API intact but allow you to change implementation easily. For example, if you instead define your Helper module as

```
import { doSomethingElse } from './Elsewhere';

export function formatStr(str) {
    // Do something with str
    str = str.toUpperCase();

    // do something else with str
    str = doSomethingElse(str);

    return str;
}
```

You introduce a level of indirection to `doSomethingElse`. You can break down that function into many more, or choose to actually get it from a library and save yourself the maintenance and testing around it. All the while the Helper module remains unchanged and maintains exactly the same API as before.